# PHP - overwrite mapping for ini file on IIS 8.5

Tags: php, iis-8.5

I am going to change my website PHP version from 5.2 to 7.2, I have synced all of setting from php.ini in 5.2 version to the new one, but when running the phpinfo.php file on the server, most of the variables have no value. especially session.save_path and error_log, however, I have set all of them in the php.ini file. also display errors is on.

```
session.save_path = C:\PHPSessions
error_log = "C:\PHPSessions\php-7.2.10_errors.log"
```

I have checked for permissions as well, IUSER,IIS_IUSRS,users,admin all have full control.

now my website not loading, and it's my info file:
[image: I don't know where it overwriting]

ps: I have changed the php version on my local using wamp, and there wasn't such problem, so the code is fine.

[image]

Comment: Check out the value for Loaded Configuration File in your phpinfo() output; you may not be running the configuration you have been editing.

Comment: I have checked multiple times, and it's running the one I have been editing.

Comment: Do you have a web.config file which specifies PHP parameters?

Comment: <add name="php-5.2.12" path="*.php" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="E:\web\php5.2.12\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
`            <add name="PHP7.2.10" path="*.php" verb="*" type="" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="E:\web\php7.2.10\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="" responseBufferLimit="4194304" />
            `

Comment: It seems that you didn't delete the settings for PHP 5.2. Please run the report and edit your question to include that, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/php-diagnostics.html So that others can see what exactly you configured.

Comment: I am not familiar with this tool, but I will add the result in question

Comment: I find out that my php.ini file had a syntax error inside of it, so it wasn't loading correctly, now I see values on phpinfo but still my website not loading!